# migrate from pure OpenMP to the hyprid with MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

I am conducting a global maximization for a rather daunting high dimensional problem. To make my life easier, my building-block program was ported to OpenMP and ran smoothly fine.

The main program actually consists of 4 building-block programs, each working under different setting. And the real task of mine is to feed the main program with a long list of parameter combinations. My preliminary thinking for overcoming this challenge is to divide the list into 10 smaller parts in parallelism.

Suppose the computing capacity I have is a high performance cluster on which a node has 8 cores (or 16 threads). My question is: is it correct that I simply use the usual MPI routines like MPI_INIT and its pals to complete the extension of my program from OpenMP to the hybrid with MPI? Is it correct that I simply specify the following in my PBS script:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#PBS -l nodes=40:ppn=8
...
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=16
...
```

Or else do I need to think deeper by using alternative routine like MPI_INIT_THREAD to have my work done?

=============[edited June 24, 2014]

Here is the PBS file I finally figured out for my multi-threaded MPI program (without overlapping communication across OMP and MPI). My program works in this way: one multi-threaded MPI process is executed per node. Each node fully forks workload to all the threads that are physically associated with it. In addition, since I am also using Intel MKL and Intel MPI, I made corresponding adjustment in the PBS script below.

```
1 #!/bin/bash -l
2 #PBS -l walltime=01:00:00,nodes=32:ppn=8,pmem=2000mb
3 export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8
4 cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR 
5 mpirun -perhost 1 -np 32 -hostfile "$PBS_NODEFILE" \
6   -env I_MPI_PIN_DOMAIN omp \
7   -env KMP_AFFINITY compact ./main
```

Besides, be sure to add -mt_mpi into the compiler flags to correctly enable the support of Intel MKL.

Comment: Be aware, if you have 8 cores, using 16 threads might not be a good idea. See http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/637.html

Comment: ...be also aware when running on more than one node, that your `export OMP_NUM_THREADS` line is likely only being executed on the first node, and others may use only the default number of threads.  If you want to change that environment variable on all threads, you may have to either put the line in your `.bashrc` (or whatever) file, or have the executable you launch be a script that first sets your environment variables, and _then_ runs the real executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that it's not required to do anything special here in terms of MPI as long as you're never calling MPI functions in a parallel section. If you are going to do that, you need to use `MPI_INIT_THREAD` and provide the level of thread safety that you require.

In reality, you should probably do this anyway. If you're not going to be doing multiple MPI calls in parallel, then you can get by with `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED`, otherwise, you probably need `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`.

Comment: I just want to have a confirmation. Were you saying as long as I am never calling MPI functions in an OpenMP parallel section, my extension from pure openmp to its hybrid with MPI is rather simple? That is, it is OK if the structure of my main program is something like MPI_INIT() and MPI_FINALIZE() enclose the Openmp parallel regions, but not the other way around? Thanks.

Comment: No, you'll still just call init and finalize once at the beginning and end of your entire program. The difference is that if you want to do MPI calls like `MPI_SEND` or `MPI_RECV` inside your OpenMP parallel section, you'll need to call `MPI_INIT_THREAD` with `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` right after you call `MPI_INIT`. If you're going to use OpenMP at all though, you should still call `MPI_INIT_THREAD` after `MPI_INIT` with `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED` to indicate that only one thread will be calling MPI functions. More on the man page: http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Init_thread.html

Comment: @Wesley Bland I am still a little confused. Without considering multithreading, does a thread exactly represent a core? Suppose my program runs on multiple nodes (each with multiple cores/threads). If the OpenMP part of my program orchestrates all the cores on a single node to do some parallel computation, and the MPI part of my program is left outside OpenMP parallel regions to take care of only the plain sending/receiving communication among nodes, I am wondering whether calling MPI_INIT_THREAD after MPI_INIT with MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED is also suitable for my case? Thanks.

Comment: Before trying to answer this question, something needs to be cleared up `thread` != `core`. A thread is a software construct describing a lightweight execution environment. A core is a piece of hardware that describes a subset of the CPU. The number of threads you execute does not necessarily equal the number of cores that your computer has. Try rewording your question now and see if it still makes sense.

Comment: @WesleyBland Multithreading is disabled on my university's machine, so I would assume one core can only execute one thread at a time in my case. I port the major part of my program to OpenMP so that the computational workload can be distributed across cores within a single node, and in the very beginning and end of my program I've already added MPI_INI and MPI_FINALIZE and outside OpenMP parallel regions some other MPI subroutines to do communication among nodes. May I have your confirmation that I need to include additional subroutines you mentioned to make the program work properly?

Comment: Yes. You should use `MPI_INIT_THREAD` with `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED`.

Comment: @WesleyBland In this tutorial (see [here](http://user.cscs.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/CSCS_Application_Data/Files/Presentations/Courses_Ws_2011/Multi-Threaded_Course_Feb11/Day_2_Session_3.pdf)), the author simply replaces MPI_INIT() with MPI_INIT_THREAD()? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. I think so. It's easy to find out. If it doesn't work, do the other thing.